# openCV calibration results on a more distorted image

Tags: opencv

I am doing an OpenCV calibration but the undistort result is not what I expect. It looks more distorted than the original image.
I am using just one calibration image as I found other people doing similar approach but I also tried with multiple square images pattern.

Here are some details of what I'm doing:

```
calibrationFlags = cv::CALIB_FIX_K4 | CALIB_FIX_K5
```

using calibrateCamera and the undistort function.

```
cv::undistort( InputImage, OutputImage, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, cameraMatrix );
```

I tried already with initUndistortRectifyMap and getOptimalNewCameraMatrix but the results are also similar.

What am I missing?

Here are the original and undistort images:

[image: Original]
[image: Matched points]
[image: Undistort]

Comment: any reasons why u fix k4 and k5? Are the circle's centers detected correctly and accurately?

Comment: @Micka I saw other sources using fix k4 and k5 but there is no difference on the result. I added the image with matched points.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, while checking the circle's centers I found the resolution issue!

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: I was using a half resolution image for calibration and then use a full resolution to apply the undistortion. All images in the process must (?) have the same resolution.